# While taking a nn.Module (which consists of other nn.Modules) to cuda, aren't all the internal nn.Modules supposed to go to CUDA too?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

I have this module VideoSegmentationNetwork which consists of 3 nn.Modules

1. CNNEncoder(nn.Module)
2. TransformerEncoder(nn.Module)
3. CNNDecoder(nn.Module)

```
class VideoSegmentationNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VideoSegmentationNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.cnnencoder = CNN_Encoder()
        self.transenc = TransformerEncoder(input_dim=EMBEDDED_DIMENSION, num_layers=2, num_heads=2)
        self.cnndecoder = CNN_Decoder()
```

I have defined this network as:

```
   model = VideoSegmentationNetwork()
   model.to("cuda:0")
```

While doing this, all three Classes are in CUDA when I check.

**"SO WHERE IS THE PROBLEM? o.O"** - You might ask.

Well, it comes inside TransformerEncoder(nn.Module) class, which is another class. It has a custom made MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module) class. The error exactly pops in, the MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module) class.

The MultiHeadAttention class is like this:

```
class MultiheadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, num_heads):
        super(MultiheadAttention, self).__init__()
        self.query_layer = nn.Linear(input_dim, input_dim)
        self.key_layer = nn.Linear(input_dim, input_dim)
        self.value_layer = nn.Linear(input_dim, input_dim)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(input_dim, input_dim)
```

The error exactly pops in forward(self, x) method in the class. The error exactly says this:

[image]

So I was wondering, doesn't taking VideoSegmentationNetwork to cuda, take everything inside it to cuda too? Or I am missing something here, and you guys have some suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: Did you move the data as well to GPU? because both your model and the data should be on the same device.

Comment: Yes I did. But this has been solved now, it was a stupid mistake to be honest.